# Can you send a variable to another computer so I can access it?

Tags: javascript

How can I take an variable from a prompt that someone else inputted and send it to my computer so I can access the variable data. For example if I did this:
var = prompt("Whats your name?")
How do I access the variable to see the persons name?
Also, if I wrote the variable code wrong, can you tell me what it should be?
Please can you also not press the down arrow, it's just a question since I am a new programmer.

Comment: you'd need to send it to a centralized place (normally a web server with a database), and then other computers would read the value from that centralized place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is a client side programming language, this means that it only operates within the client (ie. your web browser). You cannot "send" a variable from one computer to another due to this fact. If you are interested in server-side programming languages PHP is very accessible and is of similar syntax to JS. But as to your original question, that is not possible and I'd advise you break your problem down more to figure out what you really need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Although JS is a client-side language, NodeJS is a JS runtime that allows us to work server-side without having to learn a completely different language.